# Отправление сообщения пользователю при изменении на сайте

Tags: python, telebot

Я делаю бота через telebot, который отправляет свежие новости человеку. Я уже сделал парсер который полностью вытаскивает новости из сайта, но проблема в том, что я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы бот при добавлении новости на сайт, сразу же отправлял сообщение пользователю с этой новостью. Я подумал сразу же о цикле while с задержкой time, но это сильно будет нагружать сервер, как я думаю, и это не очень практично.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, у вашего сайта с новостями есть система уведомлений или RSS лента. А может и вообще API имеется. Можно брать оттуда сообщения о публикации новой статьи.

Извиняюсь за ответ. Мне не хватает репутации для возможности комментирования.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, мой сайт к сожалению самый обычный новостник, поэтому апи нет, но вы подкинули идею, гораздо легче просто найти api с новостями, спасибо!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что найти новостной ресурс с RSS лентой будет проще :)

Comment: К сожалению, я не знаком с таким, а опыт с api имеется)

Comment: @Utsiye Ничего сложного там нет. Вот библиотека: https://pypi.org/project/rss-parser/

Comment: Большое спасибо!